# Assign 3 typed numbers to a variable in Processing

Tags: variables, processing

I am making a paint program in Processign and want to allow the user to type 3 numbers to change int r;.
I want to know if I could do something to take three typed numbers and assign them to a single variable like int r. Such as typing 2, 5, 5, and storing them as int r =255;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could use an array.**

An array is a variable that holds multiple values.

```
int[] r = {1, 2, 3};
int x = r[0];
```

[Here](https://www.processing.org/reference/Array.html) is the Processing array reference.

**You could create your own class.**

Better yet, you could create a class that keeps track of your 3 values:

```
class MyNumbers{
   int r;
   int g;
   int b;

   public MyNumbers(int r, int g, int b){
      this.r = r;
      this.g = g;
      this.b = b;
   }
}
```

Then you just create an instance of that class and pass in your values:

```
MyNumbers rgb = new MyNumbers(1, 2, 3);
int r = rgb.r;
```

[Here](https://www.processing.org/reference/class.html) is the Processing class reference.

**You could use the `color` type.**

If all you want to store are rgb values, consider using the existing `color` type in Processing:

```
color c = color(1, 2, 3);
int r = red(c);
```

[Here](https://www.processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html) is the Processing color reference.

**You also might want to look into the [ArrayList](https://www.processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) or [HashMap](https://www.processing.org/reference/HashMap.html) classes.**

Comment: Yeah I would use that but I want the user to be able to enter custom values

Comment: @SnapDraggen Any of my solutions support that. What exact custom values are you talking about? Why exactly won't it work?

Comment: While the program is running I would like the user to be able to hit r to activate the red variable then hit 3 numbers such as 2, 5, 5, then hit r again and have it store all three numbers as a single variable like r = 255;
Sorry it was a bit confusing

Comment: @SnapDraggen Again, any of my solutions would support that.